# How to merge two dataframes but based on multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have two dataframes:
df1:

```
    A       B      C       D   
0   test1   test2  test3   test4
1   test22  test33 test23  test432
2   test54  test32 tes353  test98
```

df2:

```
   A        B
0  test98   value1
1  test1    value2
2  test33   value3
```

Basically, ColumnA from dataframe 2, can be the value of any of the columns from dataframe A. In the end I want a desirable output like this:

```
    A       B      C       D         Value
0   test1   test2  test3   test4     value2
1   test22  test33 test23  test432   value3
2   test54  test32 tes353  test98    value1
```

Of, course this is only a prototype, I have a complex dataframe...
So, is there a way to merge this based on this conditions that I described?

UPD:
Of course df2 has more columns
df2:

```
   A        B         C
0  test98   value1   value5
1  test1    value2   value6
2  test33   value3   value7
```

and the end goal is to have df1 like this:

```
    A       B      C       D         Value      Value2
0   test1   test2  test3   test4     value2     value6
1   test22  test33 test23  test432   value3     value7
2   test54  test32 tes353  test98    value1     value5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), then [`groupby.first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.first.html):

```
df1['Value'] = df1.stack().map(df2.set_index('A')['B']).groupby(level=0).first()
```

*NB. this requires to have a non-duplicated index.*

Output:

```
        A       B       C        D   Value
0   test1   test2   test3    test4  value2
1  test22  test33  test23  test432  value3
2  test54  test32  tes353   test98  value1
```

If you have other columns in `df1`, only keep the columns of interest:

```
df1['Value'] = (df1[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']]
                   .stack()
                   .map(df2.set_index('A')['B'])
                   .groupby(level=0).first()
                )
```

Comment: Hi @mozway, thank you for your time to answer, this one works perfectly in the case that i describer. I have updated my question because I have a more complex dataframe and df2 has more column. How this would reflect on your answer? can you please check my updated question?

Comment: And i think i have a problem in my case, because not all the values are unique, from column A and I was getting this error: InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Comment: @user14073111 it shouldn't matter if the values are not unique, the code takes the first valid value. You can also get all values by using `df1.stack().map(df2.set_index('A')['B']).dropna().groupby(level=0).agg(','.join)`. I believe your issue is due to the index. Try to run `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)` as an initial step before my code. If this doesn't work, please provide a reproducible example.